# PHP Redirecting

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database, after the redirect I want a table row to display the row information using that rows id. How would I type that?

I built an edit.php and a login.php, now when I click edit then it redirects to the login, now after I login correctly it redirects to edit.php, problem is that the edit.php is not displaying the rows for me to edit.

Assuming this is all the code that is needed, how do I correct this:

```
if($hash == $results[0]['hash']) 
{ $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results[0]['id'];
redirect(''); } else $errors['username'] = 'Login failed.';
```

Ok this is the code that is working now:

```
if($hash == $results[0]['hash']) 
{ $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results[0]['id'];
Header( "Location: http://localhost/flagship/web/edit.php?id=" . $_SESSION['user_id'] ); }
else $errors['username'] = 'Login failed.';
```

Just that its fetching only the first row from the table, how do I get the other rows to display?

Comment: can you explain in detail , what you want and what you have done till now for that ?

Comment: header("Location: ../web/edit.php?id=" . $row['id']);

Answer (score 4):

Use `header` function:

```
header('location: ../web/edit.php?id=' . $row[$id]);
```

Comment: did not work, I just want to know how to fetch the id? forget about $row

Comment: @Dale where is this ID coming from?  If it's from the request, e.g. `http://someurl.com/somefile.php?id=xxx` then use `header('location: ../web/edit.php?id=' . $row[$_REQUEST['id']]);`

Comment: I want the login.php to remember which id I clicked so that I can edit the details on edit.php

Comment: Then your question is totally off.  What you need to do is store the ID into user session.  If you have no idea what I'm talking about here, read about PHP session handling: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: I have that already, where should my redirect go to: if($hash == $results[0]['hash']) {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results[0]['id'];
                redirect('');
            } else
                $errors['username'] = 'Login failed.';

Comment: I can't really say.  It's your application - and the target of the redirect is up to you.

Comment: i want it to redirect to the edit.php, but to the id of the edit page, the path is localhost/flagship/web/edit.php?id=[] or something like that. I just don't know how to type the path correctly, let me know if you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

```
header("Location: ../web/edit.php?id=$row[$id]");
```

Comment: id not work, I just want to know how to fetch the id? forget about $row

Answer (score 0):

You want to redirect the browser? try this:

```
Header( "Location: http://www.domain.com/web/edit.php?id=" . $row[$id] );
```

**EDIT**

with the code now in your question it would be:

```
if($hash == $results[0]['hash']) 
{ $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results[0]['id'];
Header( "Location: http://www.domain.com/web/edit.php?id=" . $_SESSION['user_id'] ); } else $errors['username'] = 'Login failed.';
```

Comment: id not work, I just want to know how to fetch the id? forget about $row

Comment: its working, but now its only fetching the first id for every other id as well, so that means i'm seeing the first row of my table. How do I get the other rows with there ids?

Comment: @dale change the `0` inside of results to select a different result. If you want to redirect all of them you'll probably have to pass that number into your results call.

Answer (score 0):

```
Header('Location:edit.php?id='.$row[$id].'');
```

Comment: I want the login.php to remember which id I clicked so that I can edit the details on edit.php

Answer (score -3):

If you have to use php to do it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

My personal favorite way to redirect is to

```
echo "<script>window.location('set location');</script>";
```

Comment: That is actually a bad choice, since you are gonna have to assume the client has javascript support; and the client not always is a web browser.

Comment: Ouch -2 already.  It might be bad, but it is a way to change the location after headers have been sent.